# Checking if user is logged in or not using sessions: java servlet

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have two type of users: admin and user.
Here's what I am doing in **Login servlet**

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String user=request.getParameter("user");
    String pass=request.getParameter("pass");

    HttpSession session=request.getSession();


    String name="user",type;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select utype from users where email=? and pass=?");

        ps.setString(1, user);
        ps.setString(2, pass);

        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()) 
        {
            type=rs.getString(1);
            if(type.equals("a"))
            {
                session.setAttribute("loggedIn", "admin");
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("admin.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }
            else
            {
                session.setAttribute("loggedIn", "user");
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
                rd.include(request, response);
            }


        }
        else
        {
            request.setAttribute("message","Username or password error!");
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And on **account.jsp** page I am checking is user is logged in or not.Here's the code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ include file="headpl.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <script>
              //have some code here
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <%
        if(session.getAttribute("loggedIn").equals("admin"))
            {
                response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
          }else
           if(!session.getAttribute("loggedIn").equals("user"))
        {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
         }  
   %>
     //some html code here
  </body>
  </html>
```

The code was running fine before I added the session checks.
Now, when the admin is logged in and types the URL of the account page, he is redirected to **admin.jsp** (that's fine), when user is logged in he is allowed t go to **account page**  , But when no one is logged in I get an exception:

```
  exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:370)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jsp.account_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.account_jsp:128)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:322)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5.11 logs.
```

I think that the `NullPointerException` is due to the fact that no session variable exists since No one is logged in. I saw several answers on SO but none of them worked for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: something like the following maybe? if(session.getAttribute("loggedIn") == null)

Comment: Tried that already, no change :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "loggedIn" session attribute is missing so the equals method call rejects a NPE.

You can try to check null value of "loggedIn" session attribute before manage its value.

Something like this :

```
if (session.getAttribute("loggedIn") == null) {
     response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
} else if(session.getAttribute("loggedIn").equals("admin")) {
     response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
} else if(!session.getAttribute("loggedIn").equals("user")) {
     response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}
```

Comment: I don't know how but it worked when I copied your code. Maybe the order of `if statements` was the reason. I wrote: `if(session.getAttribute("loggedIn").equals("admin"))
{
 response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
}else
if(session.getAttribute("loggedIn")==null))
{
 response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}else{}' How silly of me :P

Comment: Yes it was because your first if statement rejected NPE and the JSP generation just stopped.

Answer (score 1):

you need to first check weather `session.getAttribute("loggedIn")` is null or not before compare to `admin` or `user` string.
If no one user is logged in that time you don't have session attribute `loggedIn` in session and you got `null` when try to read value from session using `session.getAttribute("loggedIn")` and `equals` method throw exception because it compare your string with null.

```
if(session.getAttribute("loggedIn")!=null && session.getAttribute("loggedIn").equals("admin"))
{
    response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
}
else if(session.getAttribute("loggedIn")!=null && !session.getAttribute("loggedIn").equals("user"))
{
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}  
else  
{
    response.sendRedirect("defaultPage.jsp");
}
```

It always best practice to check for `null` value before comparing to any string or any object with other object.

Comment: yeah that's right, I checked null after checking admin :D

Answer (score 0):

Or just use:

```
String username = request.getRemoteUser();
if ("user".equalsIgnoreCare(username)) {
    .....do something....
}
```